# Розовый экран в скомпилированном приложении Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скомпилированное приложение показывает warning следующего содержания:

> your device does not match the hardware requirements of this application

После этого сообщения, экран покрывает розовый цвет..

С чем это может быть связанно, если я не добавлял шейдеры и не делал ничего навороченного?
Это просто небольшой 2d платформер.

Версия unity 2019.2.16f1

Comment: Телефон не соответствует минимальным требованиям

Comment: У меня есть подозрение. Вы когда компилируете - вы указываете версии OS, для которых осуществляется сборка бинарника. То есть, грубо говоря, "Собери мне эту программу под андроиды версий..." какие там версии бывают? Ну и вот, вы ГДЕ ТО в настройках указали эти версии, и забыли. На эмуляторе работает? Работает! там то всегда последняя версия андроида. Берем настоящее устройство - опаньки, туда три года как апдейты не приезжали и версия OS устарела. Попробуйте покоапаться в настройках собирающей системы и добавить версию того андроида, который на телефоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это [видео решило мою проблему](https://youtu.be/E22R1Ls7bCQ).

Если кратко, то чтобы исправить розовый экран нужно перейти в:
File > build Settings > Player Settings > Player > Other Settings; После, поставить галочку на Auto Graphics API и убрать с Multithreaded Rendering.

Я не знаю сколько может быть причин у этой ошибки, но мне этот способ помог.

Answer (score 0):

Встречал эту ошибку при работе с эмулятором Андройд Студии. Если как мне вам необходимо тестировать приложение с выключенной галкой auto graphics api. Расширенные настройки>Настройки>Установите OpenGL ES API Level> Renderer maximum(up to OpenGL ES3.1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами (прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]), что именно вы предлагаете.